# In a society based around moral relativism, how would the courts or government in general work?

Tags: society, government, law, law-enforcement, philosophy

In one of my worldbuilds, there is a very popular and atheistic philosophy that is based around absolute moral relativism and total opposition to religion. But, I'm struggling to come up with ways a society that has embraced this philosophy wouldn't immediately collapse into anarchy. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pretty much every country, on earth has a different way for the courts and government to function. In fact within a country you can have vastly different court systems depending on where you are, the state judicial systems of the US are a great example of this. Given the diversity of legal systems in the world this seems like more of a brainstorming question than a specific worldbuilding problem.

Comment: Sure, but those individual societies don't buy into total moral relativism.

Comment: Welcome Nick T, there is a [help section](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) at the top right corner to give you an idea what kind of questions are suitable for this site. Please try to focus on a single problem. Asking a question looking for “any help at all” is always best handled in the help section first.

Comment: I would begin by thinking hard about the meaning of the phrase *absolute relativism*, and its relationship with *relative absolutism*. (Anyway, there are well-respected approaches to ethics which have nothing to do with religion.) (And you definitely need to explain why would the society "collapse" into anarchy. First, anarchy is not necessarily something bad. Second, from the point of view of Saudia, the USA is a country dominated by moral relativism, and yet it is very far from an anarchist society.)

Comment: Because human beings want some stability, those who have some power will use it to force their relative morals on others. Thus, where the Mafia Godfathers live is a fairly crime free area as they do not want petty criminals operating near them. Even in wild west boom towns, the barkeep would hire "muscle" to keep their bars orderly.

Comment: One of your worldbuilds? I think you mean "present-day [North] America".

Comment: @Matthew I don't think America is without morals. They still have their four moral pillars of Singing the National Anthem; Eating a Cheeseburger the Size of your Head; Shooting your Assault Rifle at the Sky; and Bombing the Middle East.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem based on a false assumption.  That something cannot be said to be intrinsically good or bad is independent of a society codifying things as being good or bad *to society*.

Many of the items passed down as religious tenets are societal constraints - murder without consequence is disruptive to society, as individuals are valuable to a society and losing one without an overwhelming societal good counterbalancing the loss is unsustainable.  This doesn't say that murder is itself *bad*, but that permitting it will not allow one's society to prosper.

Similarly theft, poor sanitation, etc.  If your society is interested in being *a society*, then the principle they adhere to is that they want the society to continue... and therefore activities damaging or disruptive to a sustainable society should be trammeled by rules, laws, and punishments for violation.

If moral relativism is embraced as an absolute, then what you would see is a total lack of extenuating circumstances in trial.  If someone kills someone else in any circumstance other than accident or self-defense, there would be no degree of murder, nor "crime of passion" - murder is murder, and no one cause for murder is better (or worse) than any other.

Similarly, littering and industrial dumping would be tried in the same fashion - though in that case, the punishment would probably be adjusted to be commensurate with the damage done to the society.

Ultimately, if your society is interested in being a society, but has no other motivator, all actions will be measured against that one precept.  If they are not, then yes, anarchy will likely reign, because society needs participants.

Comment: As an addendum - a society with sufficient information on things deleterious to society would likely be fairly utopian, as the things that allow the smooth functioning of society generally also provide security and comfort to its members.  As people are human, however, there could be some ugly outliers, where a given group is vilified in order to better unify the rest of society.  (This, too, is something common to many religions.)

Comment: There is an idea here but I don't see how you reasoned towards "what you would see is a total lack of extenuating circumstances in trial".

Comment: An example of an extenuating circumstance is I do a murder but only because some third party threatened my family. No one would agree the circumstance makes the murder less harmful or immoral of an act in itself. But that is a different question than "what is to be done about this Daron fellow?"

Answer (score 0):

I guess they use some non moral proxy. The classic one would be: Is it profitable? Did it increase production?

Brave New World sort of did this, although in the BNW they had arguably elevated hedonism to the status of morality.
Every decision was made on the basis of how much pleasure it gave / how much economic growth it provided.

Answer (score 0):

If some person or group of people seized power by force and imposed a system of laws by force, the society wouldn't necessarily collapse, as long as the laws weren't draconian enough to provoke an uprising.

Forcing one's laws on others doesn't seem compatible with the philosophy of moral relativism, but you didn't say that everyone believes in it, just that it's very popular. It's at least logically consistent for a society to exist in which almost all members begrudgingly obey laws to avoid punishment while believing that there should be no laws. I don't think it's logically consistent for most people to believe in moral relativism while also agreeing to what amounts (whatever they might call it) to a shared, enforced moral code. Previous answers suggested forms of "the good of society" or hedonism as alternatives to a moral code, but they are not alternatives at all, just specific moral systems.